# Sorting a stack in ascending order using a temporary stack

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, stack, fifo

```
void sortStack(Stack *s)
{
    /* add your code here */
    Stack temp;
    temp.ll.head =NULL;
    temp.ll.size =0;
    int item_popped;
    int item_temp;
    while (isEmptyStack(s)!= 1) {
        item_popped = pop(s);
        if (isEmptyStack(&temp) == 1) {
            push(&temp,item_popped);
            continue;
        }
        item_temp = peek(&temp);
        if (item_popped > item_temp) {
            push(&temp,item_popped);
        }
        else {
            while(item_popped <= item_temp || isEmptyStack(&temp) != 1) {
                push(s,pop(&temp));
                item_temp = peek(&temp);
            }
            push(&temp,item_popped);
        }
    }
    while (isEmptyStack(&temp) != 1) {
        push(s,pop(&temp));
    }
}
```

Assuming, my inbuilt functions eg pop(),peek(),push() etc are correct, why doesn't this code to sort a stack in ascending order work. I receive no output when printing after sorting.
For example, given a stack 1,4,5,3,2 --> I want to get 5,4,3,2,1 (in ascending order) by using a temporary stack.

Comment: Can you make this into a [mcve]?

Comment: I don't see any variable storing/updating the `head` of the list during the sort, my guess is that you are printing using the tail node.

Comment: We need a proper [mcve], and you need to run this in a *debugger*, single stepping with a *known* expected behavior test to *debug* your code and discover where it fails your assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. First, this is wrong:

```
else {
    while(item_popped <= item_temp || isEmptyStack(&temp) != 1) {
        push(s,pop(&temp));
        item_temp = peek(&temp);
    }
    push(&temp,item_popped);
}
```

Imagine going into that while-loop with both conditions being true, but the latter only being true because there is only *one* element left in `temp`. You then pop off `temp` and push onto `s`. That leaves `temp` *empty*. You then `peek(&temp)` which is wrong, because there is nothing left in temp. The result is whatever unspecified "thing" `peek` returns is now in `item_temp`.

That loop should be this:

```
else {
    while(item_popped <= item_temp) {
        push(s,pop(&temp));
        if (isEmptyStack(&temp) != 1)
            item_temp = peek(&temp);
        else break;
    }
    push(&temp,item_popped);
}
```

Second, your comparative logic will sort the list *ascending*, not descending like you seem to expect. I point this out because your statement of expectation is a complete contradiction. You said:

5,4,3,2,1 (in ascending order)

Um.. that's not "ascending order". That's *descending* order. If you're expectation is a pop-loop will report *that* sequence, then all the comparisons need reverse logic. If you're expecting an actual *ascending* sequence the code with the change I showed should do that.